# Attributes or ACL to be set for readonly of the owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my S3 bucket, I  am trying to set a ACL for a secure file  , similar to "chmod 600 myfile" in Linux.

What is the almost equivalent option to chmod 600?

`"bucket-owner-read" or private"`

I tried reading the documents and started to learn S3cmd options .  Looking for  the right command to set a permission similar to "chmod 600" in Linux and to list and confirm the same is set for  the file.

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd` (which is rarely updated).

Comment: Who currently has access to the bucket, and how have they been granted that access?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are **private by default**.

The only way to access the objects are **if a policy specifically grants access**. This could be a policy on an IAM User, IAM Group or IAM Role. Access could also be granted via a Bucket Policy on that particular bucket.

There is also an older-style 'ACL' that can grant object-level permissions but these days this is best avoided. In fact, AWS recommends [Disabling ACLs for all new buckets and enforcing Object Ownership - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html).

So, your problem is probably not "how to grant access" but rather "**how to prevent other users gaining access**", especially if the Admins have been granted `"s3:*"` permission to access any S3 bucket. This will typically involve adding `Deny` policies to prevent other users from accessing the data. However, Deny policies are notoriously difficult to get right.

An extreme option is to **create a different AWS Account** and put the sensitive data in a bucket in that 'other' account. This is typically used to protect confidential information such as HR data or personally-identifiable information. You would then limit who has access to the 'other' account.